# add and remove specific array elements using array.splice()

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to add to a specific part of an array, and then deleting a specific part of the array, in this case the end value using `arr.splice()`?

i currently do this like so:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
arr.splice(0,0,"test");
```

which should return:

```
"test",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

i then do:

`arr.pop();`

which should return:

```
"test",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

I was wondering if it's possible to do this via the `arr.splice()` method or if there is any cleaner method to do the same, as potentially i'll be doing this a few times, so i would end up with something like:

```
arr.splice(0,0,"test");
arr.pop();
arr.splice(1,0,"test2");
arr.pop();
```

looking at the [array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) documentation it suggests i can only delete the element in the position i'm putting the new element into, not a different one.

Comment: Why would you want to do that with `splice`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The short answer is no, but `.pop()` is an `O(1)` operation, so I'm not sure it's necessary to try to condense this into a single statement.

Comment: you could take an item without adding an item with splice (if necessary). but pop is easier as operation.

Comment: @NinaScholz I think OP wants to prepend an item as well as remove the last item, in 1 command, which is not possible to my knowledge

Comment: @mhodges, right it coulf take two different operations but only at the given index.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yeah. I think the effect the OP is trying to create is an array with a static length, and when items are inserted, the last item is pushed off the end of the list. I don't see a way to do this without 2 operations (unless, of course,  you are inserting into the position of the last element)

Comment: @mhodges you are correct yes, if there is no valid way to achieve this tidier than what i have, i suppose then that is the answer i'm looking for. i was hoping the splice method had an additional param to choose a separate index to delete or something similar did the same thing

Comment: @gardni Are you wanting this for brevity or for efficiency? If you just want a single statement in code, you could just write a function that does both operations and takes the additional index as a parameter like you want `splice` to do

Comment: for adding a values at start, you could use `unshift`, instead of `splice`.

Comment: @NinaScholz Same time complexity as `splice` but doesn't allow you to insert anywhere you want. In OP's second example at the bottom, `arr.splice(1,0,"test2")` it indicates that it will not always be inserting at the beginning of the array

Comment: @mhodges ok, i didn't read that.

Comment: @mhodges i guess both, i figured a method that does it all would be the most concise and efficient method, by the sounds of it, the function would be a quicker and tidier option that individual pops?

Comment: @gardni I'm not going to post this as an answer, because I don't think it's exactly Kosher, but this may point you in the right direction: https://repl.it/repls/BouncyMysteriousAlpinegoat

Comment: @mhodges thanks for this, i think for the purposes of what i require, this might be overkill somewhat, do you think it's worth posting an answer suggesting what i want from the array.splice is not possible and the only option would be a seemingly more complicated function? alternatively i'll see about closing the question

Comment: I would probably refer to @NinaScholz for that question - I genuinely don't know

Comment: i have actually no answer (maybe i don't understand the problem correctly).

Answer (score 0):

In answer to my original question as confirmed in the comments. It is not possible to provide a separate index to insert and another to remove in an array using the splice method or potentially any other single statement in javascript. The best approach to try to achieve this in a single statement if i really needed it would be to create your own function, which really seems counter productive for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.from()` to set the `.length` and values of specific indexes of an array in a single call

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

arr = Array.from({length:arr.length - 1, ...arr, 0:"test"});

console.log(arr);
```

To achieve the pattern described at Question you can alternatively use a loop and `Object.assign()`

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var n = 0;
var prop = "test";
while (arr.length > 1) {
  Object.assign(arr, {length:arr.length -1,...arr, [n]:!n ? prop : prop+n});
  ++n;
  console.log(arr);
}
```